# Mouse Key Hook - Key listener not firing

Tags: c#, mousekeyhook

I'm using the [Global MouseKeyHook](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook) to listen, for both mouse clicks and key presses, whilst playing a video in a VLC activeX control. The mouse click listener triggers fine, and works as expected. But the key press/down listeners don't fire. I've attached some of the code below, any help would be appreciated.

Subscribe to the events

```
    public void playVideo(string videoPath, bool loop)
    {
        stopTriggered = false;

        this.loop = loop;
        this.videoPath = videoPath;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        this.BringToFront();

        m_GolbalHook = Hook.GlobalEvents();
        m_GolbalHook.MouseClick += m_GolbalHook_MouseClick;
        m_GolbalHook.KeyDown += m_GolbalHook_KeyDown;

        axVLCPlugin21.Focus();
        axVLCPlugin21.playlist.items.clear();
        axVLCPlugin21.playlist.add("file:///" + videoPath);
        axVLCPlugin21.AutoLoop = loop;
        axVLCPlugin21_Pos = ScreenPositons.Screen1_Start;

        axVLCPlugin21.playlist.play();
    }
```

Event triggered code

```
    private void m_GolbalHook_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //Not triggering at the moment
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Right:
                shiftRight();
                break;
            case Keys.Left:
                shiftLeft();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try `Hook.AppEvents()` instead of `Hook.GlobalEvents()`?

Comment: I hadn't, and that works, the key listener now fires. But the mouse listener doesn't. I can get round this by having two hooks, one global one app. 

Thanks for the help! Feel free to add this as an answer and I'll mark it. Otherwise I'll add details to the question, to help anyone else that has this issue.

Comment: That looks weird, but not so much... Actually, the keyboard has a focus, so if it's on your application, it may be possible that the global hook can't get the inputs; as for the mouse, it doesn't have a focus, so the application hook would have trouble getting its inputs. That's just a wild guess.

Comment: Or, you know, I stop saying non-sense and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30326187/global-hook-mousedown-and-keypress-events-are-not-firing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the solution I used, in case it helps others. All credit to Kilazur (see comments). It's not a perfect solution, but it works...

```
m_GolbalHook = Hook.GlobalEvents();
m_GolbalHook.MouseClick += m_GolbalHook_MouseClick;

m_AppHook = Hook.AppEvents();
m_AppHook.KeyDown += m_AppHook_KeyDown;
```

I'm using `Hook.GlobalEvents()` for the mouse listener, and `Hook.AppEvents()` for the key listener.